# How to display two alternating pictures according to season?

Tags: image, alternating

Due to taking care of my ailing elderly parents, I haven't been able to do website design for a few years.  Now I'm extremely rusty and just can't figure too much out anymore.

Inside a div, I want to have two alternating pictures (alternating every 5 seconds or so) according to the season.

If Winter, then display winter01.png and winter02.jpg, alternating.

I have the following working code for changing the div BACKGROUND according to the season, but figuring out how to make the contents two alternating pics according to the season is well beyond me.

Any help?  I would be willing to send a small Paypal donation.....

Here is the code that works changing the background image according to season:

```
<div class="homeBox">
<!--set background image according to season-->
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var north = true;
var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
if (today.getDate() > 20) month++;
var backImg = ['/windsong/images/seasonal/backgrounds/summer.jpg','/windsong/images/seasonal/backgrounds/autumn.jpg','/windsong/images/seasonal/backgrounds/winter.jpg','/windsong/images/seasonal/backgrounds/spring.jpg'];
```

document.getElementsByClassName('homeBox')[0].style.backgroundImage =
'url('+backImg[Math.floor((month+(north?6:0))/3)%4]+')'; 
    `

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for myself.  Used Cycle2 combined with a PHP script I found.

```
<!--slideshow-->
<div class="cycle-slideshow">

<?php

function current_season() {
       // Locate the icons
       $icons = array(
               "spring" => "images/seasonal/spring",
               "summer" => "images/seasonal/summer",
               "autumn" => "images/seasonal/autumn",
               "winter" => "images/seasonal/winter"
       );

       // What is today's date - number
       $day = date("z");

       //  Days of spring
       $spring_starts = date("z", strtotime("March 21"));
       $spring_ends   = date("z", strtotime("June 20"));

       //  Days of summer
       $summer_starts = date("z", strtotime("June 21"));
       $summer_ends   = date("z", strtotime("September 22"));

       //  Days of autumn
       $autumn_starts = date("z", strtotime("September 23"));
       $autumn_ends   = date("z", strtotime("December 20"));

       //  If $day is between the days of spring, summer, autumn, and winter
       if( $day >= $spring_starts && $day <= $spring_ends ) :
               $season = "spring";
       elseif( $day >= $summer_starts && $day <= $summer_ends ) :
               $season = "summer";
       elseif( $day >= $autumn_starts && $day <= $autumn_ends ) :
               $season = "autumn";
       else :
               $season = "winter";
       endif;

       $image_path = $icons[$season];

       echo $image_path;
}

?>

<img src="<?php current_season() ?>01.png" alt="" />
<img src="<?php current_season() ?>02.png" alt="" />

</div><!--end slideshow-->
```